# Renaming table and putting a view in its place on Postgres

Tags: postgresql, migration, view

I have a very central table in our database that is used by a range of applications, it has rules attached to it, triggers and all the dependencies that you can imagine. Now I would like to modify the table without causing any problems with the dependencies. I have previously been successful with doing the following but in a much less complex case:

```
alter table reconciliations rename to matches;
create view reconciliations as select * from matches;
```

What this achieves is that I could now modify the new "matches" table and for example add a column or rows, which do not need to get presented in the "reconciliations" view (by adding a where clause to filter them out).

I am on Postgres 9.5 so the view is automatically updatable. Initial tests shows that there are no immediate problems with this, so I am asking this question to know what kind of problems I should be looking for. Performance is not a big issue.

Comment: If the original reconciliations view is reading from `matches.` then just modify matches *directly* in a transaction. You don't need to create a new table for that, unless your view uses `select *` in which case, fix your view *then* modify `matches`: `BEGIN; ALTER.. ALTER.. ALTER.. COMMIT;`

Comment: The original "reconciliations" is a table which I convert to a view, which writes to the "matches" table. I use views as an abstraction layer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you do this in production, be aware of **prepared statements**. Those have already been parsed, rewritten (and the query plan cached). The effect kicks until prepared statements are [deallocated](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-deallocate.html) (which can take a long time).

To check for prepared statements (of the same session only!):

```
TABLE pg_prepared_statements;
```

The effect also extends to plpgsql functions that handle SQL commands like prepared statements internally.

Normally, prepared statements are forced to be re-planned after any change to involved objects. But your actions circumvent this security mechanism.

Also, most queries will just keep working. But not all.

#### Demo

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE foo (id int);
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (4);
PREPARE x AS SELECT foo FROM foo WHERE id > $1;  -- uses row type
```

This works:

```
ALTER TABLE foo ADD COLUMN t text;
EXECUTE x(3);  -- automatically re-planned
```

But this does **not**:

```
ALTER TABLE foo RENAME TO foo1;
CREATE VIEW foo AS TABLE foo1;
ALTER TABLE foo1 ADD COLUMN t text;

EXECUTE x(3);  -- not re-planned!
```

> ```
> ERROR:  cached plan must not change result type
> ```

[The manual on `PREPARE`:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-prepare.html#SQL-PREPARE-NOTES)

> Although the main point of a prepared statement is to avoid repeated
>   parse analysis and planning of the statement, PostgreSQL will force
>   re-analysis and re-planning of the statement before using it whenever
>   database objects used in the statement have undergone definitional
>   (DDL) changes since the previous use of the prepared statement. Also,
>   if the value of [`search_path`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-SEARCH-PATH) changes from one use to the next, the
>   statement will be re-parsed using the new `search_path`. (This latter
>   behavior is new as of PostgreSQL 9.3.) These rules make use of a
>   prepared statement semantically almost equivalent to re-submitting the
>   same query text over and over, but with a performance benefit if no
>   object definitions are changed, especially if the best plan remains
>   the same across uses. An example of a case where the semantic
>   equivalence is not perfect is that if the statement refers to a table
>   by an unqualified name, and then a new table of the same name is
>   created in a schema appearing earlier in the `search_path`, no automatic
>   re-parse will occur since no object used in the statement changed.
>   However, if some other change forces a re-parse, the new table will be
>   referenced in subsequent uses.

The above is another example where the *"semantic equivalence is not perfect"*.

Comment: Excellent point! Do you see any other problems with replacing a table with a view like this?

Comment: @David: I have done it before and don't see any other immediate problems - which doesn't mean there are none. It's a piece of complication and complications lead to problems ...

Comment: I really appreciate your help! Do you have any thoughts on the two ideas for solving the same problem that I introduced here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/161720/dependency-management-by-decoupling-table-name-from-table-key

I am primarily interested in the creating of aliases and depreciation of old names. I don't know how to do this for tables on Postgres.

Comment: Also I'd like to point out that any views referencing original table would still reference the same (renamed to "matches") table and not the new view "reconciliations"